# Is performing two morphological Dilation with 3x3 structuring element equal to one with 6x6 structuring element?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

My question is simple. It might be too simple. But the thing is while working on one of my projects I used the following lines to dilate a binary image.

```
cv::dilate(c_Proj, c_Proj, Mat(), Point(), 2);
```

Which is basically dilating the binary image with a 3x3 rectangular structuring element. From the last argument you can see I am performing 2 iterations of this operations, which is equivalent to:

```
cv::dilate(c_Proj, c_Proj, Mat(), Point(), 1);
cv::dilate(c_Proj, c_Proj, Mat(), Point(), 1);
```

My question is this:
Instead of performing two iterations, if I perform only one iteration using a 6x6 structuring element, is this equivalent to the above code in terms of accuracy and performance? Is it faster as the image is iterated only once?

Comment: For the record, since answers below are all wrong: composing two 3x3 kernels results in a 5x5 kernel. If you have a good implementation of the convolution, the operation can be computed independently of the kernel size, so it’s better to do one large one than multiple small ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dilation with the same kernel can be expressed with two convolution operations:

```
("YourImage" convolve "DilationKernel") convolve "DilationKernel"
```

Because of the properties of convolution, this operation is equivelant to:

```
"YourImage" convolve ( "DilationKernel" convolve "DilationKernel")
```

A convolution of a 3x3 kernel with itself will result in 5x5 matrix, so your 6x6 assumption is wrong.

In terms of performance, there is so much to consider. In my previous internship, our aim is to use as small kernel as possible because of performance losses of bigger kernels. Rule of thumb is small kernels act faster on an image because simply you can store and retrieve them using CPU registers, without accessing L1 or L2 caches. Also if your kernel fits in  registers, you can easily use SSE instructions.

Parallelization of the convolution is another story, and I don't have much practical information about it. So I don't know this empirical facts still holds if using a parallelized implementation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake out. I am still looking for a performance comparison. I think I might have to devise my own method to compare both operations

Comment: A dilation is not a convolution, and cannot be expressed as such. The dilation is a non-linear operation, the convolution is linear. But strangely enough, replacing “convolution” by “dilation” everywhere in this answer, it turns into a correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to measure the performance yourself but it seems logical that one dilation with a 6x6 element should be faster. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29) sais that binary dilation is associative. This means that if a 3x3 rectangle dilated with another such rectangle gives a 6x6 rectangle then indeed two dilations by 3x3 are equivalent to one dilation by 6x6.

Comment: Why "does it seem logical"? A naive implementation would have to look at 6*6 neighbors for each pixels, or 2*3*3 Pixels. 6*6 > 2*3*3

Comment: @nikie, you are right. Though for rectangular structuring elements this can be optimized with prefix sums. I'm not very familiar with algorithms used in image morphology.

Answer (score -2):

First, two 3x3 in squential should be same to a 5x5.
Second, as for the performance, 5x5 is slower. There are some rough ideas about it: if you consider raw implementation (based on loop), the number of calculation should be 3x3xWxHx2 comparing to 5x5xWxHx1.

Comment: We're about a decade later, and have GPU's now. You can't just say that a one-step algorithm (5x5x1) is slower than a two-step algorithm (3x3x2).

Comment: When talking about rectangular kernels, the dilation can be implemented with only 6 comparisons per pixel (3 comparisons per pixel per dimension), no matter what the size is. So it is always better to do one pass with a larger one than multiple passes with a smaller one. This is true whether you’re on GPU or CPU.